# Laravel Admin lte preloader

Tags: html, laravel, preload, preloader, adminlte

I have a laravel project using admin lte theme. This Amin lte has a preloader with some animations. I am currently facing one problem, this preloader only preloads after the html shows. Normally with pure html and css, I use a script tp make the loading icons and show the page only after it loads everything. But for some reason using admin lte, he shows the animation, but only after almost 1 second during this second, it shows the pure html without the css, like really fast. How can I make this preload come first or then I can disable and make my own, but my pages don´t have a standard html, they are like this:

```
@extends('adminlte::page')

@section('title', 'Fire Hazard')

@section('content')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usualy happens when you put html outside the content area, try to put everything inside the

'''
@section('content')
@endsection
'''